# Definition of normal extension.

Tags: field-theory, definition

> Let $E/F$ be an algebraic extension.
>
> Then, $E/F$ is normal iff $E$ is a splitting field of a family of polynomials in $F[X]$.

So does this mean that if $E$ is a splliting field of a given one family of polynomials in $F[X]$? Or splitting field for every family of polynomials?

( That is, $\exists$-family or $\forall$-family?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is "$\exists$". $E$ need not be *a* splitting field of *all* families of polynomials (that would be *algebraic closure*), nor need it be *all* splitting fields of *a* family of polynomials.

For example $E:=\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ is (a, or upto isomorphism the) splitting field for the one-element family of polynomials $X^2-2$ over $F:=\mathbb Q$. On the other hand, $E:=\mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]2]$ is not a spliting field (over $F:=\mathbb Q$): The obvious candidate polynomial $X^3-2$ splits only into $(X-\sqrt[3]2)(X^2+\sqrt[3]2 X+\sqrt[3]4)$, not completely.

Comment: why is it specially named as "normal", not just saying "splitting field for some family"?